# How to move data from filemaker pro to microsoft sql server studio using odbc for filemaker

Tags: mysql, sql-server, excel, talend, filemaker

My client has maintained the database in FileMaker pro, now I have to move this database to another database that is Salesforce, they have provided me the ODBC of FileMaker Pro, I want to export the complete data in an excel or csv form Filemaker to insert it in salesforce. 
I can export the data in Excel from SQL Server , so can I get the data from my filemaker using the given odbc to my SQL Server or any other database from there I can get the excel of data.

Please do help me, response would be much appreciated.

Thanks in adavnace

Comment: Not sure what exactly your question is about. If you want to move the data from FileMaker to another DB, why can't you export it from FileMaker itself, without requiring an ODBC connection? -- P.S. Note that Excel is not a good choice as an intermediate format. Use either the Merge format (.csv with field names in the header) or XML.

Comment: Actually, I do not have access to FileMaker it self, I have only the odbc for Filemaker provided by the client.

Comment: Could you please tell me , how to fetch the data by using this odbc of filemaker pro

Comment: Not really, because I don't understand the context. If you have established an ODBC connection to the FM file, you can query it using (a subset of) SQL. For details, see: http://www.filemaker.com/help/15/fmp/en/#page/FMP_Help%2Fsharing-via-odbc-jdbc.html%23

Comment: Thanks much, even I am not sure about the context, they had given me the ODBC of filemaker with the host and other required credentials, I was thinking that I need to install the ODBC then after installing it I need to use it as a data source to get the data.

Comment: Any other way do you know by which I can get the data, I have currently now ODBC for Filemaker, HostName and required credentials

Comment: If you mean via ODBC, then no - there is no other way to get the data except query it using SQL. -- Of course, it would be much more simpler for your client to export the data and send it to you. --  "*even I am not sure about the context,*" I meant the context in which **you** operate the ODBC connection.

Comment: And you are certain that the table formats of both applications are the same?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you were given an ODBC connection to the FileMaker Server. In this case you do not need to install FileMaker ODBC on your workstation, but need to add ODBC source to SQL Studio as a linked server.

Expand your connection in object explorer and select "Server Objects/Linked Servers". Add new server.

Comment: Thank you, you got me correct, I will check and let you know If I am able to link server